# Set focus of codemirror instance based on container

Tags: javascript, jquery, codemirror

I have multiple instances of codemirror running on my page. Some are hidden and you can move between them using tabs. What I would like to do is be able to set the focus based on the container.

At some point the instance was initiated like this:

```
var cmInstance = CodeMirror(target, options());
```

So I would either like to be able to get the instance that was initiated on that container by using the container, something like:

```
cm = target.getCodeMirror();
```

or perhaps set the focus based on the container, something like:

```
target.setFocus();
```

Is anything like this possible or should I rather keep a record of individual instances in an array or something?

Comment: CodeMirror will add a property `CodeMirror` to the container DOM node, pointing at the editor instance.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Okay so I opted to track my instances of codemirror in an array and address them based on an ID that I keep track of and link to the `target`. Once I have my instance I can just set focus using the codemirror method `cmInstance.focus();`

Currently I feel this is the best solution.